# BigQuery - Different unnesting outcome

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I'm getting different outcomes for an unnesting operation over a table with the following schema

```
planet STRING 
moons  RECORD 
   name      STRING 
   satellite RECORD
           name STRING
```

Unnest is applied in the following way

```
select planet, moons.name, satellite.name 
from table, 
     table.moons, 
     moons.satellite
```

In the case where a moon doesn't have a satellite, the outcome of the table above doesn't show the moon (i.e., no row). What gets me puzzled is that the same query has been run in the past, where the outcome did contain the moon name + null in the satellite column in the case no satellite is found.

Any suggestions on what could be happening here?

Comment: In your query, `satellite` is an array of a struct, correct ?

Comment: yes, I already figured out what was going on. In the case of having no satellites (i.e., an empty struct) the cross join outcome is such that no moons are displayed either. Switching to a LEFT JOIN needs to happen so it can be recovered

Answer (score 0):

The CROSS JOIN outcome changed because of a new data format for nulls. In the case where no satellite is found for a moon, having an explicit [NULL] vs [] makes the difference. To recover the full join, one needs to replace the CROSS JOIN by a LEFT JOIN so nulls (or empty arrays) are preserved.